# Classes not coming through using react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is driving me crazy.  I am trying to use React.js to place some simple HTML elements, but they are not coming through as typed.  Namely, the classes I am assigning them aren't showing up in "inspect element" and therefore my stylings cannot be assigned:

For instance, rendering this:

```
<a href="#" class="button" onClick={this.props.deleteTask} value="button_change">Sign Up</a>
```

comes out like this:

```
<a href="#" value="button_change">Sign Up</a>
```

no class there.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: className, not class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use className instead of class, as indicated here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

For example

```
<a href="" className="button"></a>
```